# why the same formatting spec show different result?

Tags: python-3.x

I define `tps = ['depp slee', 1, 2, 3]` as a list  and run `f""" [setT]:{{[br]<stat>:"{{status:[{tps[0]}]}}" """`. it work well.
but run `f""" [setT]:{{[br]<stat>:"{{status:[{0}]}}" """.format(33)` it raise error, it looks like the same, why this crashed?

```py
In [55]: tps
Out[55]: ['depp slee', 1, 2, 3]

In [56]: f""" [setT]:{{[br]<stat>:"{{status:[{tps[0]}]}}" """
Out[56]: ' [setT]:{[br]<stat>:"{status:[depp slee]}" '

In [57]: f""" [setT]:{{[br]<stat>:"{{status:[{0}]}}" """.format(33)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [57], in <module>
----> 1 f""" [setT]:{{[br]<stat>:"{{status:[{0}]}}" """.format(33)

ValueError: unmatched '{' in format spec
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the formatting. Remove the `f` and try `""" [setT]:{{[br]<stat>:"{{status:[{0}]}}" """.format(33)`

If you evaluate

```
f""" [setT]:{{[br]<stat>:"{{status:[{0}]}}" """
```

you get `' [setT]:{[br]<stat>:"{status:[0]}" '`
In this expression you see that the first curly bracket does not close. Furthermore, a `:` appears in the opened expression. This causes the error message. Try for example `'{x:d'.format(33)` or even more minimalistic `'{:'.format(33)`.